# php shell_exec system cannot find the path specific

Tags: php, shell, exec

I want to run the Php script in the background so after doing all the searching, this is what i get.
When i run this command on command prompt.

```
shell_exec('php test.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

but it keep showing "**The system cannot find the path specific**".

/dev/null is a file? I could not find what is problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is php in the exec path on the user executing this script?

Comment: yeah, its inside xampp/htdocs

Comment: Is your script called in the same directory as the test.php file... otherwise you probably need to give the full path to the file

Comment: can this command works on windows OS?